# How to prepare for or deal with a Third-Party app falling out of support?

Tags: appexchange

I apologize for not having a more concrete example; this is a hypothetical that we are considering as we are attempting to build out architecture.

Suppose we install a third-party app from app exchange, and some portion of our org depends on it. What happens if the third party that supports that app drops off the face of the earth? I imagine that it would continue to function in the short term, but would it be in danger of not keeping up with future changes to the platform?

How do organizations that use third-party apps mitigate this danger? What approaches can we take to make sure we don't end up depending on crumbling infrastructure? Do any tools exist that can help with this?